# Clicking HTML button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have to click a HTML button programatically which is on the 3rd page of the website . The button is without id. It has just name type and value . The HTML code of the button is given below

```
<FORM NAME='form1' METHOD='post' action='/dflogin.php'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtId' value='E712050-15'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtassId' value='1'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtPsw' value='HH29'><INPUT TYPE='hidden' NAME='txtLog' value='0'><h6 align='right'><INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='btnSub' value='Next' style='background-color:#009900; color:#fff;'></h6></FORM>
```

i am using the following code to click it

```
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allButtons

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") =  "Next" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")

        End If

    Next
```

But i cant able to click it . I am using the vb.net 2008 platform. Can anyone tell me the solution to click it?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem as you. The InvokeMember looks correct so I can only assume its not picking up the correct html element. Try refering to the element explicitly using the value. The following code worked for me but I have adapted it for you:

```
 For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allButtons
      If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("E712050-15") Then
        webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        Exit For
      End If
 Next
```

Good Luck :)